# Questions related dual vector and covector through a example.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors

I am finding dual vector very confusing to understand. I would like to understand it using example:
Let $V=\Bbb{R}^3$, $v=\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\5\\ \end{bmatrix} ∈ V$ and

$f_1, f_2, f_3 ∈ V^*$ are defined as follows
$$f_1=\left<\begin{bmatrix}1&3&7 \end{bmatrix}^T,\cdot\right>,
f_2=\left<\begin{bmatrix}2&5&6 \end{bmatrix}^T,\cdot\right>, 
f_3=\left<\begin{bmatrix}5&2&1 \end{bmatrix}^T,\cdot\right>
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&3&7 \\2&5&6\\ 5&2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\5\\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}46\\49\\21\end{bmatrix}
$$

1. Above: Which vector/vectors are dual vectors?
2. Is dual vector == Covector?
3. Is $V^*=\Bbb{R}^3$

   **If yes**: Is it appropriate to write $f_1, f_2, f_3 ∈ V^*$ because $f_1, f_2, f_3$ are scalar values then how is it possible for $f_i$ to be element of $R^3$?

   **If No**: Then what does this statement mean "dual vector space has the same dimension as $V$" (Ref: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DualVectorSpace.html)
4. What is functional here?
5. Is it appropriate to represent$f_i$ the way I have done if not what would be a correct way?
6. What is the RHS vector $\begin{bmatrix}46&49&21\end{bmatrix}^T$ is called?
7. What is the vector $v$ is called as?
8. **Any other comments.**

Comment: Questions ... verified. 
Answers ... not verified (missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $v$ is a vector, $f_i$ are dual vectors.

2) Yes.

3) $V^*$ is isomorphic to $V$, but not canonically. Not canonical means you have to choose an isomorphism (there is no "best"). The isomorphism you chose is given by a scalar product (other scalar products would give others).

If yes) $f_i$ are not scalars, they are linear maps! They eat a vector and give a scalar.

4) A functional is an other word for (sometimes linear) function. Normally it gets used when the vector spaces are infinite dimensional (like in acion functional).

5) It is an appropriate way.

6) The matrix transforms $v$ to the values $f_i(v)$, listed in a vector. Another (maybe pretentiously complicated) way of interpreting it is: By choosing $f_i$, you chose a basis of $V^*$. The RHS vector are the coordinates in that basis of the dual of $[2,3,5]^t$, where the dual is determined by your scalar product.

7) I don't understand the question...

Comment: Thanks @Lucas for the reply. Regarding 3): I am still not clear: Is $V^*=\Bbb{R}^3$? What I have understood is that the vectors [1 3 7], [2 5 6] & [5 2 1] span  $V^*$and hence in $\Bbb{R}^3$. AND if this is the case then in my opinion writing $[f_1, f_2, f_3]∈V^3$ is more correct. You wrote "fi are not scalars, they are linear maps! They eat a vector and give a vector.": Half part is Ok, but I think they eat a vector and give a SCALAR.

Comment: 3) yes, $V^*=\mathbb R^3$. What I tried to point out is that $=$ is often not enough, one wants to know the isomorphism. And the "not canonical" part is just that one has to artificially choose an isomorphism. The scalar objection is totally right, I edited it in.

Comment: To $f_i\in V^*$: this means that they individually are in $V^*$. It is true that $[f_1,f_2,f_3]\in {V^*}^3$, but this will formally NOT be a matrix, but rather a triplet of covectors (maybe some programs will interpret it as matrix, but then it is just notation. In reality "useful" is more useful then "formally correct").